# Is $10^{-3}$ error or tolerance? .Find a solution accurate within $10^{-3}$ for $() =  ^{3} + 3 − 5$ on$ [1, 2].$

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, bisection

[image]

According to the algorithm,$f(c)=0$ 0r $(a-b)/2<TOL$ is stop procedure.
My problem is in this question, Is $10^{-3}$ error or tolerance. If it is an error, should I check $|aₙ-bₙ|<10^{-3}$ to stop the iteration? and if it is TOL should I check $(a-b)/2<TOL$ to stop iteration?
I have confusion about the differences between tolerance and error and the relationship between them.

Comment: The title doesn't quite match the question. It would probably be a good idea to either remove that part from the title or include it into the question (as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tolerance is usually synonymous for error. As stated in the procedure, you want to stop when $(b-a)/2<10^{-3}$. Note that $|a-b|=b-a>0$ by the initial condition and that the distance the actual root is from $c$ is at most $(b-a)/2$ when the root is at $a$ or $b$ (the farthest points from $c$, the midpoint).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If an answer answers your question, do not just give thanks. Comments should be reserved for commenting on the answer itself, such as asking for more clarifications. Instead, make sure to [accept it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate to future readers that your question was satisfied by the answer. This should naturally go for all of your questions.